# How to configure HAproxy Ingress controller in Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, haproxy, kubernetes-ingress, sql-server-2019, haproxy-ingress

So we have a SQL server deployment with replica=2 in K8s which I need to make load balanced. I'm using Haproxy ingress controller to achieve this goal but I'm stuck in configuring Haproxy. I'm trying to configure the Haproxy based on [this link](https://www.haproxy.com/blog/dissecting-the-haproxy-kubernetes-ingress-controller/) and I don't know how to present my two pods to the ingress!

There is this part of the link says:

```
---
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1beta1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  name: web-ingress
  namespace: default
spec:
  rules:
  - host: foo.bar
    http:
      paths:
      - path: /
        backend:
          serviceName: app
          servicePort: 80
```

The issue is that in "spec.rules.host" section, I don't have any domain rather I have two IPs belong to my SQL pods! How am I supposed to represent my pods to the ingress? Am I doing right? 
I've looked it up alot, but no luck!

P.S: What is the best practice for Load Balancing SQL server?

Comment: An ingress object configures L7/http load balancing, you need to configure your controller to make L4/tcp load balance.

Answer (score 1):

A DNS system translates hostname to IPs.With a domain registered with DNS system you can add a mapping of hostname to IP in the `/etc/hosts` file of the system from where you want to access the hostname.